# Missing directory for Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, centos, systemd

I'm following a tutorial for How To Deploy a Node.js Applications Using Systemd and Nginx on CentOS but I'm stuck on the step where it requests I run he following commands:

cd
curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

After running, source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh bash comes back with: No such file or directory.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

The full tutorial can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-node-js-applications-using-systemd-and-nginx

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh;
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Albeit the [git repo](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) says to run:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
```